# How is it possible to make 8 (...) 8 (...) 8 = 6?

Tags: formation-of-numbers

$$8\text{ }8\text{ }8 = 6$$

Add in any required number of mathematical symbols to make the above equation work.

How is this possible? Can somebody explain?

Comment: Sqrt(8+8/8)! Is an answer I think, no time to post it as such though